# ANTLR grammar for building expression tree using antlr4

Tags: java, regex, antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

[image]

I'm quite new to `antlr`, I'm trying to develop grammar in `antlr4.x` to help to build an expression tree, as shown in figure, from the following expression:

```
*a=value1 and c.size()>10 or (d=value3 and  compare(after(today(),2),value4)) and  compare(before(today(),2),value4)*
```

Comment: Can you post your grammar?